# operator << overloading for class

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

`A` is a C++ class written by me:

```
class A
{
private:
    int _num1;
    int _num2;
public:
    A(int num1, int num2)
    {
        _num1 = num1;
        _num2 = num2;
    }

    ~A(){}

    int getNum1() { return _num1; };
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, A const &obj) { return os << obj.getNum1(); };
};
```

there is a template's function `printArray`:

```
template <class T>
void printArray(T* arr, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

When I write in main function:

```
    A arr4[4] = { A(1,1), A(1,4), A(6,6), A(0,0) };
    printArray(arr4, 4);
```

there are this errors:

> E0344 too many parameters for this operator function.
>
> C2804 binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters.
>
> C2333 'A::operator <<': error in function declaration; skipping function body.

What is the problem and how to fix it?

> of course I included iostream

Comment: put `friend` before `std::ostream`

Comment: doesnt helps, gives:
>  C2662 'int A::getNum1(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const A' to 'A &'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems:
1. you should use `friend` keyword to overload `<<` operator
2. `getNum1` should be `const`

```
class A
{
private:
    int _num1;
    int _num2;
public:
    A(int num1, int num2)
    {
        _num1 = num1;
        _num2 = num2;
    }

    ~A() {}

    int getNum1() const { return _num1; };
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, A const &obj) { return os << obj.getNum1(); };
};
```

Comment: it works now but it's a problem with printArray now
it prints:
    1
    49305896
    6
    2

Comment: @arik your code, after being corrected as per above, works for me without problems. I have got 1
1
6
0

Comment: you write, i got an error in other function too, it solved